# Why is typescript not able to figure out that a variable cannot be undefined in a branch of a ternary?

Tags: typescript

```
const size = boundingBox?.getSize()
return (boundingBox !== undefined) ? (<Box width={size.x} />) : (<></>)
//                                                ^ TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Why is this error happening? The signature of getSize does NOT optionally return undefined. It's only undefined because of the first line, this causes the type of `size` to become established as `const size: THREE.Vector3 | undefined`, which is why the first branch of the ternary on line 2 produces TS2532 (blind to the fact that it cannot be undefined in the first branch).

So, this means that the types are stuck and cannot be further refined contextually. Is this a limitation of the language or a bug in the implementation?

Comment: Also: I know that I could change the conditional statement to `size` to resolve the situation and that is what I just did in my code. The question is why is TS so capable of a lot of complex strongly typed features, but fails at this basic capability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of Typescript, and a very reasonable one: Typescript can perform control-flow type narrowing on variables depending on tests that you do on those variables, but not depending on tests that you do on *other* variables.

In this case, the condition `boundingBox !== undefined` narrows the type of the variable `boundingBox`, but it does not narrow the type of the variable `size`. Typescript does not keep track of dependency relations between the types of multiple variables.

If it did, this would greatly complicate the type system and would likely make compilation much slower; in general if you had many variables with union types depending on each other, it would have to keep track of an arbitrary subset of a Cartesian product, whose size would be exponential in the number of variables.

Comment: See [microsoft/TypeScript#12184](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184) for something like a canonical answer to this question, especially [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184#issuecomment-260162839).

Comment: Thank you very much, what a perfect answer. I wish compilers could offer these things as optional features. I really hope TS takes on flow analysis. If it does it will have a long and impactful future. Without it, it will just be a passing fad.