# Why isn't these treated the same in typescript

Tags: typescript

Some questions for all of you TS gurys:

when you do TSX you don't want to much logic in the template part. Therefore it is common to do:

```
const isTrue = sant && !!obj

return (
<div>
 {isTrue && <Component obj={obj} />}
</div>
)
```

However TS would consider obj as obj | undefined in this case, even though I added a guard. If I move the logic down in the markup it works, like this:

```
return (
<div>
 {sant && !!obj && <Component obj={obj} />}
</div>
)
```

I also coded a quick example for you to test:

```
let sant = true 
let obj: null| {foo:string} = {foo: "bar"}

if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    obj = null
}

const isTrue = sant && !!obj

if (isTrue) {
    console.log(obj.foo) // <- possibly null? WHAT?
}
```

I also have this problem:

```
let obj: null | {foo:string} = {foo: "bar"}

if(Math.random() < 0.5){
    obj = null
}

const fooString = obj?.foo || new Object()
const fooString2 = obj?.foo || {} // <- This will always be "{}", why?
```

Thanks!

Comment: `sant && !!obj` is interpreted as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) but when it is abstracted to a variable it loses that special meaning.  The second one has to do with `{}` being a special type that's sort of "anything" so it broadens the type, but I'm not explaining that well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is typescript not able to figure out that a variable cannot be undefined in a branch of a ternary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66502045/why-is-typescript-not-able-to-figure-out-that-a-variable-cannot-be-undefined-in)

Comment: The second part is simply because `{foo:string}` is a subtype of `{}` so the union `{foo:string} | {}` can be simplified to `{}`.